# Android Bluetooth Application hangs in the call of cancelDiscovery

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

My Android application is very simple. All it does is executes the following loop infinitely (pseudocode)

```
int longEnough = 12sec;
if (btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
  btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
}else{
  btAdapter.startDiscovery();
  wait(longEnough);
}
```

The problem is that it works *very* unstable. Sooner or later, but it always gets frozen. The debugger shows that somewhere deep inside of Android, the call of `initSocketNative` was unsuccessful. Here is the excerpts from the logcat

```
11-07 17:00:57.969: WARN/System.err(1473): java.io.IOException: Unknown error: 0
11-07 17:00:57.969: WARN/System.err(1473): at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.initSocketNative(Native Method)
11-07 17:00:57.969: WARN/System.err(1473): at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.<init>(BluetoothSocket.java:153)
11-07 17:00:57.969: WARN/System.err(1473): at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.<init>(BluetoothServerSocket.java:77)
11-07 17:00:57.969: WARN/System.err(1473): at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.createNewRfcommSocketAndRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:983)
11-07 17:00:57.969: WARN/System.err(1473): at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:935)
11-07 17:00:57.969: WARN/System.err(1473): at com.mobileleader.sync.obex.connection.BluetoothConnection$AcceptThread.run(BluetoothConnection.java:136)
```

After the crash occurred, all subsequent calls of `adapter.isDiscovering()` return `true` and Android ignores all calls of `cancelDiscovery()`. Once, I've been waiting for 10 minutes (just for the sake of experiment) till it will revive. No luck, of course.

The test environment includes a few 2.3.x Android devices.

The question is: what I faced with?

Comment: what do u mean by "wait" in your pseudo-code?
do you mean u listen for 12 seconds or do u call the method wait of this thread?
posting the real code would be helpful

Comment: it doesnt make much sense 
its impossible to debug without any code..

Comment: @Tom, the problem is inside of startDiscovery, it doesn't matter what the "wait" means. The real code is multithreading and properly synchronized/accessed, besides, I spent a lot of time to narrow the bounds of the problem's source. Don't waste your time reviewing my code, I know what I do. ;)